# Running any variation of "ng update" triggers this error : "connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.97.96:443"

Tags: angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

**Versions**:

Angular CLI: 6.0.7

Node: 8.9.4

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 6.0.3

**Repro steps:**

Started the process of upgrading from 5.2 to 6. Followed all the steps up until the part about updating angular CLI. Ran the following commands to update cli, which worked fine:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
```

**Observed behavior:**

However, when running:

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

I get this error:

```
connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.97.96:443
```

**Desired behavior:**

My angular-cli.json file is not converted to angular.json. Tried using different variations of ng update. Tried installing cli again using yarn. Made sure there is no corporate proxy set up and that there is no npmrc file.

Any temporary workaround ?

Comment: You can always try to manually convert your `angular-cli.json` file to the new format in `angular.json`, might take some time, but it'll get you unstuck. I get stuck trying to upgrade `@angular/core` after that though so it only gets you to the next impasse...

Comment: @whotyjones yeah thats what i had to do in the meantime, ive also had to manually update all my other packages using npm

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but as I was behind corporate proxy, so setting proxy configurations fixed my issue.

```
npm config set proxy http://your.company.proxy:port

npm config set https-proxy http://your.company.proxy:port
```